# Using character \ (backslash) in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, url

I want to populate a text field with a path, for example `\Layers\SiteVisit`
but when I try to use `'\Layers\SiteVisit'` I get an error. It seems the `\` symbol is not recognised as a character within the `' '`

Can someone please advise?

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `\\` if you really want to use that character (eg for consistent display purposes).

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `/` because `\` is used to escape any special character.

For example,

```
file_name('\Layers\SiteVisit.foo')
```

returns `'?ayers?iteVisit.foo'`

but

```
file_name('/Layers/SiteVisit.foo')
```

returns `'SiteVisit.foo'`

Comment: Thanks!! the \ worked to open the file automatically in a relative path which was my intention. [% @project_folder %][%PATH-ACTIO%]